# Iterating over a csv.reader object and handling blank data without using pandas/dataframes

Tags: python, list, loops, csv, iteration

I'm rather new to iterating lists, and having looked at some youtube videos and other resources I have been able to import a CSV file and create an array of string values. The CSV file has blanks, so when I go to loop through and convert to an integer, it fails. When I use an IF statement with an isinstance as float to handle errors I get a return of 0 in my output.

I'm trying to do this without built in libraries to get a better understanding of how to iterate through lists. I feel pretty silly asking such a mundane question here, any guidance on how to handle the errors would be greatly appreciated.

```
with open('WHO.CSV', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)
    avg_100k = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if isinstance(row[7], float) == True:
            avg_100k = avg_100k + float(row[7])
            j = j + 1

print(j)
print(avg_100k)
```

The output I get for both both `j` & `avg_100k` is 0.0. Why are the averages not being calculated correctly?

Comment: CSV's have no column types, they are all strings, so why would `row[7]` ever be a float?

Comment: I'm trying to typecast it from strings to float so I can sum them, I'm not sure if that is the right approach?

Comment: `isinstance` is running before your type-cast, though

Answer (score 0):

If you could supply your input data, or a sample of it it would be much easier to help you diagnose the problem.

Try something like this though which instead of using `isinstance()` looks at the data pulled out from the CSV and determines directly from the value if it is empty.

```py
with open('WHO.CSV', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    next(csv_reader)
    avg_100k = 0
    for i, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        if row[7] != "" or row[7] != " ":
            avg_100k += float(row[7])

print(i)
print(avg_100k)
```

Comment: Hi James, my CSV file is found here:

http://www.who.int/tb/country/data/download/en/

I'm still not getting a valid output, could you please take a look when you have a moment? Thank you for humouring me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that that value is not an empty string, you would do this

```
if not row[7].strip():
```

If you want to aggregate one column, you can do

```
avg_100k = sum(float(row[7]) for row in csv_reader if not row[7].strip())
```